# sharepoint dashboard Designer

Tags: sharepoint-2010, business-intelligence, infopath2010, performancepoint

I have enabled the Business Intelligence center in my sharepoint site. Once i done that. I tried clicking the "RUN DASHBOARD DESIGNER". It is not opening the dashboard designer.exe.
It is showing me the error "Cannot retreive application. Authentication Error"

- The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

I am using Sharpoint server 2010. To run this.

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens when the machine on which you are opening Dashboard Designer **is not joined to the same domain** as PerformancePoint Server machine.  Another common issue is that Windows/IE is not **remembering** your credentials to pass them to the application.  See [this MSDN thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/90cb879e-1323-4e70-a2fc-1c45d6b0a756/sharepoint-2010-pps-dashboard-designer-cannot-retrieve-application-authentiation-error) for more info on that.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, you should ensure you

1. add the site to Local Intranet / Trusted Sites on IE and
2. you add the credentials you use to access your SharePoint site to [Windows
   Credentials Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyL7r.png).